# blocking Proxies with PHP

Tags: php, proxy

I put the little code on the header of php file to blocking proxies:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
  || ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']=='')
  || ($_SERVER['HTTP_VIA']!='')) {
      die("Don't use proxies, please.");
}
```

In `member.php` I put the above code and its work very well and when someone request `example.com/member.php` with http proxy this code blocks them, but when they request `example.com/member.php?action=login` this code can't block them! What am I going to do? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Proxies transmit the `X-Forwarded-For` header on a voluntary basis. If they don't, you have no way of knowing the user is behind a proxy. This is often the case, especially with the legion of anonymous proxies (i.e. proxies that don't send the `X-Forwarded-For` header) available out there. I don't know what exactly is your problem with proxies, but you're fighting a lost cause.

Comment: 1. `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']==''` does not block only users, that use proxies, and (on the other side) a proxy may also send an user-agent, if they like. 2. (just curious) Why you want to block users, that are using proxies? When they want to use a proxy, I don't see a real reason to prohibit it.

Comment: all thos variables can be spoofed with curl, the only way is to record the offending ips, and then block them at your firewall or in a .htaccess file

Comment: Congratulations, you are now blocking most corporate users.

Answer (score 0):

A blank user agent doesn't imply they're using a proxy... some people just don't like broadcasting what browser/OS they're using... As for why the login script doesn't get blocked why not look at what's in $_SERVER at each stage. A simple `var_dump($_SERVER)` will show everything and tell you why what you're trying to match isn't being matched.

Comment: ummm ... the above code like this yeah ? : if (isset(var_dump($_SERVER)(['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
  || ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']=='')
  || ($_SERVER['HTTP_VIA']!='')) {
      die("Don't use proxies, please.");
}